# Expand variable number of text tags from XML data source in Excel get&transform

Tags: excel, xml, powerquery, get-transform

I'm trying to use Excel's get&transform functionality (previously known as powerquery) to import an XML data source. The data source has a list of `b` tags, each with a variable number of `d` tags in a `c2` child, such as the following:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c1>foo</c1>
    <c2>
      <d>bar</d>
    </c2>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c1>fuz</c1>
    <c2>
      <d>baz</d>
      <d>quz</d>
    </c2>
  </b>
</a>
```

When I import this data with the following query the data type for column c2.d is different for the two different rows representing the `b` items, for the first row it is a general spreadsheet cell type, for the second row it is a Table type.

```
let
    Source = Xml.Tables(File.Contents("C:\Localdata\excel-powerquery-test2.xml")),
    Table0 = Source{0}[Table],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table0,{{"c1", type text}}),
    #"Expanded c2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Changed Type", "c2", {"d"}, {"c2.d"})
in
    #"Expanded c2"
```

It seems that for the first row it automatically converts the `d` tag into a simple spreadsheet cell as there is only one and it only contains text. However for the second row it sees there are two `d` tags and hence keeps it as a table. The problem now is that I can neither load the data as is as the Table in the second row is loaded into the spreadsheet as the literal string `"Table"` leaving me without the actual data, nor can I further expand the Table using `Table.ExpandTableColumn` as it (rightly) complains that `bar` in the first row is not a table.

I presume the automatic conversion of a single tag containing text to a simple cell rather than a table happens either in the `Xml.Tables` or `ExpandTableColumn` functions. The tooltip for `Xml.Tables` shows that it has an `options` parameter, unfortunately the [documentation for `Xml.Tables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/xml-tables) does not give any details on this `options` parameter.

How can I get this second row expanded out to two rows, one each for the two `d` tags contained in the second `b` tag having the same `"fuz"` string in the first column? Such an expansion works fine if the contents of the `d` tags are further XML tags, but apparently not if the `d` tags only contain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's add a step to make sure everything is at the same level:

```
let
    Source = Xml.Tables(File.Contents("C:\Localdata\excel-powerquery-test2.xml")),
    Table0 = Source{0}[Table],
    Expandc2 = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Table0, "c2", {"d"}, {"d"}),
    ToLists = Table.TransformColumns(Expandc2,
                  {"d", each if _ is table then Table.ToList(_) else {_}}),
    ExpandLists = Table.ExpandListColumn(ToLists, "d")
in
    ExpandLists
```

The `ToLists` step turns this:

[image: Screenshot]

Into a more consistent list format:

```
c1       d
-----------------------
foo     {"bar"}
fuz     {"baz", "quz"}
```

Then you can expand to rows without mixed data types.